# I couldn't figure out class structure on Python and I have a "AttributeError"

Tags: python, oop

I have a class in textChecker.py and I want to use this class from another .py file

**textChecker.py:**

```
class Fixer:
    def __init__(self,number,word):
        self.number = number
        self.word = word

    def wordFixer(self):
        text = self.word
        text = text.lower()
        return text

    def priceFixer(self):
        text = self.number.replace(".",",")
        text = re.sub(r"$","",text)
        text = re.sub(r" ","",text)
        return text
```

**Scrapy spider file:**

```
from bot_name.spiders.textChecker import Fixer

yield{
"URUN_ADI":Fixer.wordFixer(products.xpath('//tr[2]/td[1]/text()').get()),
}
```

Everything works fine for Scrapy.
I have to fix some variables with another class because I will have a lot of spider files.

When I start crawling. I am getting this error.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'word'
```

I am new at the class structure in Python. Although I know something wrong on the Fixer class, I couldn't figure out.

Comment: You need to create an instance of the Fixer class and invoke wordFixer on the instance.  Then you need an additional parameter for the string you are passing to wordFixer.  The self then represents the instance of the Fixer class.
Your code is using the class instead of an instance of the class.  The resut of products.xpath(...) is most likely a string.  This string is then assigned to self and in the first line you are trying to access its word attribute which a string does not have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a `str` value to `wordFixer` method, but this method doesn't take `string` as a parameter. Adding `wordFixer` method to `string` parameter can help you.
Here the code:

```
class Fixer:
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number = number
        #self.word = word

    def wordFixer(self, someString):
        text = someString.lower()
        return text


obj1 = Fixer(5)
lowerCaseStr = obj1.wordFixer("UPPER CASE STRING")
```